# cmake - set - xcode attribute - implicitly link objective-c runtime support

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cmake, attributes, set

I want to set Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support to NO in cmake source file.

I tried in set_target_properties

```
XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IMPLICITLY_LINK_OBJECTIVE-C_RUNTIME_SUPPORT NO
```

but it is not working.

What is the rule to change an attribute? Or it should be predefined attribute from cmake? If it is where is the XCODE_ATTRIBUTE list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct Xcode attribute to change this setting seems to be `CLANG_LINK_OBJC_RUNTIME`. Try:

```
set_target_properties(targetName PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_LINK_OBJC_RUNTIME "NO")
```

Comment: Thank you @sakra it worked. Where can I find this list? Or are you a good forecaster? :)

Comment: If you open a .xcodeproj file in the Finder with the "Show package contents" command from the context menu, you'll find a file named `project.pbxproj`. The file contains a textual representation of all  the build settings. Among those you'll find `CLANG_LINK_OBJC_RUNTIME`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! Now I understand. I have done my other necessities with this information.